# class decorator function example

Tags: python

How can I assign `self.f` to a function using a class decorator like this `@Decorator(t=3)`?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

class Decorator:
    def __init__(self, f=None, *, t=2):
        if f is None:
            self.t = t
            self.f = None # <=== this line need to be ?
        else:
            self.t = t
            self.f = f
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f'{self.f = !r}')
        for _ in range(self.t):
            self.f(*args, **kwargs)

@Decorator
def hello4(name):
    print(f'Hello {name}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    hello4("gert")

@Decorator(t=3)
def hello6(name):
    print(f'Hello {name}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    hello6("gert")
```

I would like to achieve the same as this but then using a Class decorator instead

```
def decorator(f=None, *, t=2):
    def decorator(f):
        def repeat(*args, **kwargs):
            for _ in range(t):
                value = f(*args, **kwargs)
            return value
        return repeat

    if f is None:
        print(f'{f = !r}')
        return decorator
    else:
        print(f'{f = !r}')
        return decorator(f)

@decorator(t=3)
def hello1(name):
    print(f'Hello {name}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    hello1("gert")

@decorator
def hello5(name):
    print(f'Hello {name}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    hello5("gert")
```

Comment: I'm confused. Why do you think it should be anything else than `self.f = f`? Also, what exactly do you expect `__call__` to do if `self.f` is `None`? Why are you try to define a decorator with a default function? as of now this question does not make much sense

Comment: As soon as you use `@Decorator(t=3)`, the behavior changes. `f` is no longer passed to `Decorator.__init__`, but to `Decorator.__call__`.

Comment: @DeepSpace self.f = f wil crash when `@Decorator(t=3)` I updated the question with other example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?

I don't know if it is my python version problem

I don't know what `!r` is, and I can't use it.

So I deleted `!r`

```py
class Decorator:
    def __init__(self, f=None, *, t=2):
        if f is None:
            self.t = t
            self.f = None  # <=== this line need to be ?
        else:
            self.t = t
            self.f = f

    def __call__(self, fun):
        def repeat(*args, **kwargs):
            for _ in range(self.t):
                value = self.f(*args, **kwargs)
            return value
        if self.f is None:
            self.f = fun
            return repeat
        else:
            return repeat(fun)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@foo
def bar():
   ....
```

is equivalent to

```
def bar():
    ...

bar = foo(bar)
```

However,

```
@foo()
def bar():
     ...
```

is equivalent to

```
def bar():
    ...

bar = foo()(bar)
```

Note the difference: in the first case, `foo` is called with `bar` as an argument; while in the second case, `foo` is called, and then its *return value* is called with `bar` as an argument.

Comment: But how do you pass the function when using `@Decorator(t=3)` it in a Class decorator?

Comment: Like I said; it's passed to `Decorator.__call__`. `hello6 = Decorator(t=3)(hello6)`. There is a distinct difference between using the *name* of a class or function as a decorator and using a *call*  to the same as a decorator. Creating something that can be used either way is probably more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: Ok thanks so if i understood correctly its not possible to do`@Decorator(t=3)` and `@Decorator` let me thinker a bit about what you said so I make sure I understood.

Comment: It's *possible*, but it requires you to figure out from the arguments (or worse, using `inspect`) the context in which it was called. Far better to just require `@Decorator()` instead of `@Decorator` if you have optional arguments.

Comment: Ok and that magic of figuring out in the arguments would then be in the `def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):` right?

Comment: `__init__`, really. With `@Decorator`, `Decorator.__init__` is the decorator. With `@Decorator()` (with or without arguments), the instance of `Decorator` itself (so `Decorator.__call__`) is the decorator.

Comment: (Apologies to however may have upvoted my previous comment before I edited it to say the exact opposite thing :) )